# Pandas groupby multiple columns basis date column by epoch week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, epoch, sumifs

I want to sum up three columns that I have got in my data frame basis the date column. The catch here is that the sum up should happen basis the epoch week range.
Fro example: epoch week 14 is from 30th March 2020 to 5th April 2020 and week 15 is 6th April 2020 to 15th April 2020 and so on.
The date_time column is already in the correct datetime format.
Epoch weeks can be found here :[epochweek](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020)

My data frame looks like this :

```
   date_time                    A        B
0  01/04/2020  00:00:00         5        10
1  02/04/2020  00:00:00         5        10
2  03/04/2020  00:00:00         1        10
3  07/04/2020  00:00:00         2        10
4  08/04/2020  00:00:00         2        10
5  10/04/2020  00:00:00         3        10
```

The output should look like the following:

```
epoch_week       sum_A       sum_B
week14           11          30
week15           7           30
Total            18          60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.weekofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html) with datetimes and aggregate `sum`:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], dayfirst=True).dt.weekofyear

df = df.groupby(g.rename('epoch_week')).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   epoch_week   A   B
0          14  11  30
1          15   7  30
```

EDIT:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], dayfirst=True).dt.weekofyear

df = df.groupby(g.rename('epoch_week')).sum()
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks!

Comment: one more thing, how can I get the grand total for sum_A, sum_B columns?

Comment: @Django0602 - Can you add expcted output to question?

Comment: I have added the expected output. The total will only appear once the weeks are calculated.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!